# Which is better Flutter 2 or Flutter 3?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm asking this because I am making an article about it in Medium. This topic is interesting to me as now Flutter is quite popular it have the potential to beat Phyton's popularity in the case of Mobile Developing and other platform So Flutter 2 or Flutter 3 fellow developer?

Comment: latest statable version

Comment: How are you even asking this question a year after Flutter 3 was released?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz because I am making an article about it, duh......

Comment: For what value?  Nobody is sanely discussing anything about Flutter 2 these days.  It's gone.  Dead.

Comment: You just do not get it do you, fine then. Thanks and bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give better exp to your users than the flutter 3 is good choice and flutter 3 supports variable refresh rate for IOS.

new functionality that is different from Flutter 2 is that Flutter 3 can contribute at 120 Hz refresh rate. For Flutter 2, the same rate was 60 Hz on these devices. This means that users can have a smoother experience during animations. In addition, Flutter 3 also supports iterative live coding allowing running multiple copies of the application at once.

You can read it in detail:
https://www.google.com/url?q=https://support.google.com/websearch?p%3Dfeatured_snippets%26hl%3Den-IN&opi=89978449&usg=AOvVaw3HitsqiFdKgstY62zC5_dk&hl=en-IN&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_p8HpssCCAxUK8WEKHZAnBRwQrpwBegQIDRAE